# How to handle throttling of producer to an akka.net router

Tags: akka.net

I'm new to akka.net and trying to read as much as possible. I have 2 scenarios that I'm not sure how to deal with and would appreciate any help or pointers to examples.

1) I have a process that looks for zip files to land on a file system and then needs to process 10's of thousands of XML files contained in the zip file. I have already created my processing actors and used a dynamic router to process a few hundred requests. My question is how do I go about throttling the producer (in this case just an iterator cycling through each XML file) so that I'm not pushing 10's of thousands of messages to my router pool that at some point will get swamped. Essentially, I just want to keep the pool of actors busy all the time. Is there some standard pattern for this?

2) At some point, I may need to process the XML messages with multiple actors where each actor sends its output to the next actor in a pipeline until the final actor completes. I want this pipeline to be flexible i.e. I may need Actor 1 -> Actor 2 -> Actor 3 for one message but another one may only need Actor 1 - Actor 2. Again, is there some pattern for this. Should I look at streams as this seems to have some of what I'm after or just pass messages from one actor to another?

Any pointers would be gratefully received

Thanks in advance

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Yes akka.net streams seems to be what you need. You will be able to back pressure your producers to match consumption speeds. See [stream integration with actors](http://getakka.net/docs/streams/integration#integrating-with-actors)

For the second part you want to use flows which simply are processing steps (input and output) for your XML messages, you will be able to add/remove them flexibly. Great place to start [Akka.net streams](http://getakka.net/docs/streams/introduction)